# createWindowContainer for subclass of QWindow

Tags: qt, opengl, inheritance

I want to create a widget container over my subclass of QWindow to insert it in a MainWindow.

Here is what I did :

```
   MainWindow ui ;
   glShaderWindow window;
   QWidget *container ;

   container->createWindowContainer(window);
   ui.gridLayout_2->addWidget(container);
```

MainWindow inherits from QMainWindow. 
glShaderWindow inherits from my own class OpenGLWindow. 
OpenGlWindow inherits from QWindow and QOpenGLFunctions.

I get the error :

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘QWidget::createWindowContainer(glShaderWindow&)’
```

How can I use this function with not a proper QWindow but a subclass such as I have ?

Comment: Yes sorry I'll edit it

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, but I believe `QWidget::createWindowContainer();` is asking for a pointer to the glShaderWindow object and I don't see that represented in your window object declaration...

Answer (score 0):

Two errors

1. `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` is a static method, it returns the widget that encapsulated the window
2. Its first argument is a `QWindow*`, i.e. a pointer to a window, you are passing a value/reference.